# C# for loop need some help here - closed

Tags: c#, for-loop

I think my loop have some problem. First i consider (i=0 and i>1) but i have no idea how to write. Any one can help me?

logik i want is 
//start
=>if i=0 copy from txtbox1;
=>after that, compare i=2 and i=3 see whether are same. if same then copy from txtbox;
=>i++ until the last, every 1,2,3,4... will show differend string;
//end

```
public void OnMasterColumnChanged(BCE.AutoCount.Invoicing.Sales.SalesOrder.SalesOrderMasterColumnChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.MasterRecord.DetailCount; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                e.MasterRecord.GetDetailRecord(i).YourPONo = TxtBox1.Text;
            }
            else if (i > 1)
            {
                if (e.MasterRecord.GetDetailRecord(i).YourPONo == e.MasterRecord.GetDetailRecord(i - 1).YourPONo)
                {
                    e.MasterRecord.GetDetailRecord(i).YourPONo = TxtBox1.Text;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you also explain what logic you have to apply?

Comment: `e.MasterRecord.GetDetailRecord(0).YourPONo = TxtBox1.Text` then `for (int i = 1; i < e.MasterRecord.DetailCount; i++) { ... }` ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve and what is the problem you are facing to achieve your requirement?

Comment: @SandipPatel I had already update the logik in my question.

Comment: @sagar I had already update the logic in my question that is the problem i facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you want that:

```
public void OnMasterColumnChanged(BCE.AutoCount.Invoicing.Sales.SalesOrder.SalesOrderMasterColumnChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.MasterRecord.GetDetailRecord.Count == 0)
        return;

    e.MasterRecord.GetDetailRecord(0).YourPONo = TxtBox1.Text;

    if (e.MasterRecord.GetDetailRecord.Count < 3)
        return;

    for (int i = 2; i < e.MasterRecord.DetailCount; i++)
    {
        if (e.MasterRecord.GetDetailRecord(i).YourPONo == e.MasterRecord.GetDetailRecord(i - 1).YourPONo)
        {
            e.MasterRecord.GetDetailRecord(i).YourPONo = TxtBox1.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to check if `e.MasterRecord.GetDetailRecord` has not items at all (and `e.MasterRecord.GetDetailRecord(0)` will throw *exception*)

Comment: I did try this way but the software prompt a message = Exception from script(SO.OnMasterCOlumnChanged): Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: @ChengWan try this `e.MasterRecord.GetDetailRecord(0)?.YourPONo = TxtBox1.Text;`

Comment: @LeonelSarmiento C# show = The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer

Comment: @ChengWan I update the answer

Comment: @feeeper if (i=0) eaqual to txtbox1;     then we want to take (i=2 compare with i=3) if 2 and 3 are same then copy from txtbox1;     is there a solution for this?

Comment: @ChengWan I didn't change any logic. Just replace some code outside of the for loop. So if your code do it then my sample do it too.

Comment: @feeeper if (e.MasterRecord.GetDetailRecord.Count == 0)     in GetDetailRecord need to pass in int something alike GetDetailRecord(int)

Answer (score 0):

IF GetDetailRecord method returns the different values for different inputs then You are passing the different values below for the GetDetailRecord and checking the equal condition.

if (e.MasterRecord.GetDetailRecord(i).YourPONo == e.MasterRecord.GetDetailRecord(i - 1).YourPONo)

At one place you are passing GetDetailRecord(i) and checking with the GetDetailRecord(i - 1)

Comment: Yup, I try to check every one with the previous. That can make it replace every txtbox1. Because user only change thing in txtbox1.